# How to run Ruby on TextWrangler (Mac)

Tags: ruby, macos, textwrangler

Hey guys i know this is sounds like very stupid questions. I am newbie to coding . And i try to figure out how to run Ruby on my macbook via TextWrangler. Can someone help me ?  Please  ? Really appreciate that. i've been working on this for long time. thanks

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex0.html)

Comment: thank you !!I I just figured it out ! :D

Comment: Good Luck. Take a look at [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/ruby) as well if you want a good beginner's Ruby course.

Comment: Why not just run in terminal?